# How to fill WPF combobox with text & image at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am trying to copy a WinForms application using WPF.

In my application I have a ComboBox that is filled with the titles of movies, to let me search the movies. Now that I'm porting it to WPF, I want to use the ComboBox to display the title and poster image of the movie.

I have already created the ComboBox and the two objects, but don't know how to populate the ComboBox at runtime, because the Add method doesn't let me add the two objects at one.

```
combobox.items.add()
```

Please help me find out how to fill the ComboBox with text and images at runtime.

update: this is the xaml code for the combobox

```
<ComboBox x:Name="busca_pelicula" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="334" Margin="147,93,0,0" IsEditable="True">
    <ComboBox.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect/>
    </ComboBox.Effect>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="PeliText"/>
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="50"/>
</ComboBox>
```

and the code for fill the combobox with my data from my movie database is this

```
busca_pelicula.Items.clear();
```

using sql stuff to retrieve title and movie poster

```
BitmapImage ImagenPoster = new BitmapImage();
ImagenPoster.BeginInit();
ImagenPoster.UriSource = new Uri(wMediaPath+"Peli\\"+wNombrePoster);
ImagenPoster.EndInit();

busca_pelicula.Items.Add(? don't know what to put here)
```

Comment: Update to show what code you have so far

Comment: Use ViewModels(or similar concept) and a Binding to the ItemsSource of the ComboBox.

Comment: can you point to me to a tutorial on how to make the binding to the items text and image ?

Comment: @VincenzoRavo https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms752347(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Please don't litter your question title with unnecessary keywords, that's what the tag section is for.

Comment: thanks for the tips, sorry my mistake.

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial. It shows an example with a `ComboBox` that uses a text and an image as content of each single `ComboBoxItem`: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/combobox-control/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you have to create a class similar to this:

```
public class Movie : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ImageSource Picture { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your xaml you have to change the combo as follow:

```
    <ComboBox >
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemContainerTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Picture}"></Image>
                    <TextBlock ><Run Text="{Binding Name}"/></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </ItemContainerTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: i have added both codes to my project, but the compiler sent my two errors on InotifyPropertyChanged and PropertyChangedEventHandler "Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'INotifyPropertyChanged' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". also i don't see the code to fill the combobox list, can you show my a complete sample ? thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: thanks @Mattia Mogosso, that worked fine, just got it working right now, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: having a little problem with the code, the combo is now filled with the data (title and picture) of the database, in the first case i have used a single variable from my custom movieitem class, that attempt result in 3005 items with the last name and picture from the database, then i tried using an array from the class, but when i run the application the visual studio just break when i try to click on the combobox to see the elements, the diagnostic tools show that is using 2 gb of ram and vs2015 just break, any ideas ? how i can use a single varibale to assign the values of database ?

Comment: In this case I think that you should apply some mechanism of late-binding loading and primarly using a low-resolution images to accomplish your task.

Answer (score 0):

this is the way to declare the wpf combobox with uge amount of data to let you "virtualize" the render

```
<ComboBox x:Name="busca_pelicula" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="334" Margin="147,93,0,0" IsEditable="True" Height="55" SelectionChanged="busca_pelicula_SelectionChanged" >
        <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>

        <ComboBox.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect/>
        </ComboBox.Effect>
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemContainerTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock ><Run Text="{Binding Name}" /></TextBlock>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Picture}" Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></Image>
                </StackPanel>
            </ItemContainerTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

now is working like a charm, the combobox only renders the 10 items that it is showing, hope that helps some one.